# How can I delete contacts from iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, contacts

After OS X 10.9.3 with the restored ability to sync contacts with iTunes (over USB) was released, I finally upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks. Before I boycotted OS X 10.9 because I didn't want to give my contacts to iCloud (or any cloud, see also [What's the best solution to sync contacts from Mac to Android Phone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27936/2285)).

But when I went in the iCloud settings after the upgrade, the contacts sync was active (Isn't Apple capable to migrate a simple setting like this from OS X 10.8 to 10.9? ;-)). I immediately switched it off, but I suspect that some or all of my contacts were already synced to iCloud.

I'd like to check that no contacts are in iCloud (and delete them if some are there). What's the easiest way to do this? Just create another account, use the same Apple ID for iCloud and delete them from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start Contacts on your Mac and export/archive all contacts (as a backup)
- Go to `System Preferences -> iCloud` and disable syncing of contacts (and anything else you don't want to sync to iCloud)
- Log in to [iCloud.com](https://icloud.com) directly and delete any contacts stored there