# How to backup android device contacts on a mac?

Tags: backup, contacts, android

How do you do it? The official android files trasfer app seems to transfer only files, not contacts.

How to?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27936/whats-the-best-solution-to-sync-contacts-from-mac-to-android-phone?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I've found the way.

First you have to backup your contacts within your phone. They'll be saved as .vcf file. <<< this is the main point.

Then you can use the officia android file transfer application. You'll see the file once you can see phone's folders.

---

Side note: the application can't see your phone, first activate the USB debug from the developer options.

Hope it helps